# Configuring a wide screen (1600x900) on a desktop

Tags: resolution, screen

I just installed an 22'' wide Samsung monitor, and it looks very strange - it the right 20% of the display are wrapped to the left side of the monitor!

This is my system according to uname -a:

```
Linux ubuntu 2.6.32-34-generic #77-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 13 19:39:17 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This is my .config/monitors.xml:

```
<monitors version="1">
  <configuration>
      <clone>no</clone>
      <output name="default">
          <vendor>???</vendor>
          <product>0x0000</product>
          <serial>0x00000000</serial>
          <width>1600</width>
          <height>900</height>
          <rate>0</rate>
          <x>0</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <rotation>normal</rotation>
          <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
          <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
          <primary>no</primary>
      </output>
  </configuration>
</monitors>
```

These are the files in my /etc/X11:

```
drwxr-xr-x  10 root root  4096 2011-08-18 22:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 144 root root 12288 2012-01-15 15:48 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 2011-11-17 09:09 app-defaults
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 2011-07-19 15:21 cursors
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    14 2011-08-18 22:35 default-display-manager
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root  4096 2011-07-19 15:17 fonts
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 17394 2011-08-18 22:35 rgb.txt
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    13 2011-08-18 22:35 X -> /usr/bin/Xorg
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 2011-07-19 15:21 xinit
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 2010-04-15 15:12 xkb
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   270 2011-08-18 22:35 xorg.conf.failsafe
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   709 2011-08-18 22:35 Xreset
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 2011-07-19 15:08 Xreset.d
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 2011-07-19 15:08 Xresources
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  3730 2011-08-18 22:35 Xsession
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 2011-08-23 18:08 Xsession.d
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   265 2011-08-18 22:35 Xsession.options
-rw-------   1 root root   601 2011-08-18 22:35 Xwrapper.config
```

This is my xorg.conf.failsafe:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Configured Video Device"
    Driver      "fbdev"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "Configured Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Default Screen"
    Monitor     "Configured Monitor"
    Device      "Configured Video Device"
EndSection
```

These are the resolutions available on my system (according to xrandr):

```
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768        0.0* 
   800x600         0.0  
   640x480         0.0
```

Here is what I get from read-edid:

```
erelsgl@ubuntu:~$ sudo get-edid | parse-edid
parse-edid: parse-edid version 2.0.0
get-edid: get-edid version 2.0.0

    Performing real mode VBE call
    Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f00 bx=0x0 cx=0x0
    Function supported
    Call successful

    VBE version 300
    VBE string at 0x11100 "Intel(R)Sandybridge Desktop Graphics Chipset Accelerated VGA BIOS"

VBE/DDC service about to be called
    Report DDC capabilities

    Performing real mode VBE call
    Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f15 bx=0x0 cx=0x0
    Function supported
    Call successful

    Monitor and video card combination does not support DDC1 transfers
    Monitor and video card combination supports DDC2 transfers
    0 seconds per 128 byte EDID block transfer
    Screen is not blanked during DDC transfer

Reading next EDID block

VBE/DDC service about to be called
    Read EDID

    Performing real mode VBE call
    Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f15 bx=0x1 cx=0x0
    Function supported
    Call successful

parse-edid: EDID checksum passed.

    # EDID version 1 revision 3
Section "Monitor"
    # Block type: 2:0 3:fd
    # Block type: 2:0 3:fc
    Identifier "SyncMaster"
    VendorName "SAM"
    ModelName "SyncMaster"
    # Block type: 2:0 3:fd
    HorizSync 30-81
    VertRefresh 56-75
    # Max dot clock (video bandwidth) 150 MHz
    # Block type: 2:0 3:fc
    # Block type: 2:0 3:ff
    # DPMS capabilities: Active off:yes  Suspend:no  Standby:no

    Mode    "1600x900"  # vfreq 60.000Hz, hfreq 60.000kHz
        DotClock    108.000000
        HTimings    1600 1624 1704 1800
        VTimings    900 901 904 1000
        Flags   "+HSync" "+VSync"
    EndMode
    # Block type: 2:0 3:fd
    # Block type: 2:0 3:fc
    # Block type: 2:0 3:ff
EndSection
```

My display card is:

```
erelsgl@ubuntu:~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sandy Bridge Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Post the output from `lspci | grep VGA` to find out what card you have.

Comment: Thank you! My card is: "VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sandy Bridge Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)"

Comment: Ok. From your kernel version I assume you are running Lucid Lynx. I believe a capable display set-up tool was included there already, and it should live under System > Preferences > Display. Have you tried using that to configure your resolution?

Comment: Yes, the maximum resolution it shows is 1024x768

Comment: I believe your problem may have to do with lack of Sandy Bridge support in 10.04. I would suggest trying out 11.10 on a memory stick or CD/DVD to see if it handles your display correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by installing both of these:

http://intellinuxgraphics.org/2011Q1.html

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11223913&postcount=16

I don't know which of them actually solved the problem - just installed both, rebooted, and it worked.